# SQL group more table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like help with the problem below.
postp in first row, why not ¤Postproc1. Groupping description, sign, comp and postp.
I created the query, but one of the groupings doesn't appear the way I want it to.

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(cl.description SEPARATOR '¤') AS description, 
GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR '¤') AS sign,
GROUP_CONCAT(c.name SEPARATOR '¤') AS comp,
GROUP_CONCAT(p.name SEPARATOR '¤') AS postp,
v.version, 
v.date
FROM changelog cl
INNER JOIN versions v ON cl.version = v.id
INNER JOIN cl_type_conn clt ON clt.changelog = cl.id
LEFT JOIN cl_comp_conn cc ON cc.changelog = cl.id
LEFT JOIN cl_postproc_conn cp ON cp.changelog = cl.id
INNER JOIN types t ON t.id = clt.type
LEFT JOIN companies c ON c.id = cc.company
LEFT JOIN postprocessors p ON p.id = cp.postprocessor
GROUP BY cl.version
```

Result:

```
+------------+-----------+-------------------+---------+-------+----------+
|description |       sign|               comp|    postp|version|date      |
+------------+-----------+-------------------+---------+-------+----------+
|Desc 1¤Desc2|Type3¤Type1|Company 2¤Company 1|Postproc1|  ver 1|1631484000|
|      Desc 3|      Type4|               NULL|     NULL|  ver 2|1631570400|
+------------+-----------+-------------------+---------+-------+----------+
```

### Tables:

changelog

```
+--+-----------+-------+
|id|description|version|
+--+-----------+-------+
| 1|     desc 1|     10|
| 2|     desc 2|     10|
| 3|     desc 3|     20|
+--+-----------+-------+
```

versions

```
+--+-----------+----------+
|id|version    |date      |
+--+-----------+----------+
| 1|      ver 1|1631484000|
| 2|      ver 2|1631570400|
+--+-----------+----------+
```

cl_type_conn

```
+--+---------+----+
|id|changelog|type|
+--+---------+----+
| 1|        1|   1|
| 2|        2|   3|
| 3|        3|   4|
+--+---------+----+
```

cl_comp_conn

```
+--+---------+-------+
|id|changelog|company|
+--+---------+-------+
| 1|        1|    435|
| 2|        2|     23|
+--+---------+-------+
```

cl_postproc_conn

```
+--+---------+-------------+
|id|changelog|postprocessor|
+--+---------+-------------+
| 1|        2|            1|
+--+---------+-------------+
```

companies

```
+---+---------+
|id |name     |
+---+---------+
|435|Company 1|
| 23|Company 2|
+---+---------+
```

postprocessors

```
+---+---------+
|id |name     |
+---+---------+
|  1|PostProc1|
+---+---------+
```

types

```
+---+---------+
|id |name     |
+---+---------+
|  1|   Type 1|
|  2|   Type 2|
|  3|   Type 3|
|  4|   Type 4|
+---+---------+
```

Comment: Your GROUP BY is invalid and will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode.) What happens if you do `GROUP BY v.version, v.date` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(p.name SEPARATOR '¤') AS postp,
```

change

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(IFNULL(p.name,'')) SEPARATOR '¤') AS postp,
```